# Motorolla Phone Vs Samsung Phone UI Probem

Tags: android, android-layout

I am facing issues while developing the UI part of the application. I have two physical device for testing the app

1. Samsung A5 2016 running android 7.0
2. Moto G 5S running android 8.1.0

I have attached the images for the UI for both smartphones, I don't know how to solve this kind of problems, I am using my root layout as Constraint Layout. What is the possible fix?

**The first image is when I launch the app in A5 2016
Second in MOTO 5 GS**

[image: Samsung A5 2016]

[image: Moto G 5S]

In Moto G 5S it is giving me kinda zoom-in effect, this same problem is with some Huawei Smartphones

Layout for design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/new_white_color"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"


    android:id="@+id/rootDM"
 >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/half"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@color/new_blue_color"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/new_margin_32"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/new_margin_32"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/new_margin_32"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:textColor="@color/new_white_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/new_caption_text"
            android:id="@+id/welcomeText"
            >


        </TextView>

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/accountHolderName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/welcomeText"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/new_margin_32"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/new_margin_32"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Saad Zahoor"
            android:textColor="@color/new_white_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/new_heading_text">


        </TextView>

        <com.willy.ratingbar.ScaleRatingBar

            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/new_margin_4"
            android:layout_below="@id/accountHolderName"
            android:id="@+id/simpleRatingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:srb_clearRatingEnabled="true"
            app:srb_clickable="true"
            app:srb_isIndicator="false"
            app:srb_minimumStars="5"
            app:srb_numStars="5"
            app:srb_rating="4"
            app:srb_scrollable="true"
            app:srb_starHeight="15dp"
            app:srb_starPadding="3dp"
            app:srb_starWidth="15dp"
            app:srb_stepSize="0.5"


            >

        </com.willy.ratingbar.ScaleRatingBar>
        <TextView

            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/new_image_text_margin"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/simpleRatingBar"

            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/new_margin_4"
            android:layout_below="@id/accountHolderName"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="(4.7)"
            android:textColor="@color/new_white_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/new_caption_text"
            android:id="@+id/accountHolderRatingText"

            >


        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/new_margin_32"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/new_margin_32"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/purpleDarkBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/new_roundness"

        app:cardElevation="@dimen/new_card_elevation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/currentBalanceTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Current Balance"
                    android:textColor="@color/new_white_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/new_caption_text">

                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/currentBalanceValue"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/new_margin_4"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="200 PKR"
                    android:textColor="@color/new_white_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/new_body_text">

                </TextView>

            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"

                >

            </View>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/travellingPointsTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Travelling Points"
                    android:textColor="@color/new_white_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/new_caption_text">

                </TextView>

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/travellingPointsValue"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/new_margin_4"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="13"
                    android:textColor="@color/new_white_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/new_body_text">

                </TextView>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <com.saadBinZahoorOfficial.slipslop.MyListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/cardView"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/new_margin_32"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/new_margin_32"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/new_margin_32"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView">

    </com.saadBinZahoorOfficial.slipslop.MyListView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to be a problem, the recycler can scroll the content is any is left out. Different screen sizes and dentities plues different user text size configuration will yield different resulta. The important is the UI doesnt get chopped off out of the screen.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just change the device size of my Moto 5 GS. Now the UI is according to my need. This issue was bothering me for a long time and I was struggling to change the layout and other stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply go the device setting and change the DEVICE SIZE to small and then you will have the UI same as A5 2016